# Is $x = \frac{a}{b} = \frac{b}{a/3}$ a continued fraction? How to solve for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, continued-fractions

I believe following is a continued fraction. I'm stumped on how to solve for x

$x = \frac{a}{b} = \frac{b}{a/3}$

I know it can be re-written as

$x = \frac{a}{b} = \frac{3b}{a}$

$x = a^2 = 3b^2$

I'm unsure where to go from here.

Below are the choices

$x=9$

$x=\frac{1}{3}$

$x=3$

$x=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$

$x={\sqrt3}$

Comment: Going from $x=\frac{a}{b}=\frac{3b}{a}$ to the next line., you look like you tried to "cross multiply" to get $a^2=3b^2$.  Remember, that this was accomplished by multiplying both parts of the equation by $ab$.  Since you have three expressions chained together with an equality symbol, you really should have multiplied the far left expression by $ab$ as well.  You would have then $x\color{red}{ab} = a^2=3b^2$, not just an $x$ on the far left.  Of course, whether or not this is a useful step to keep the $xab$ rather than temporarily ignore the far left is another matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part where you wrote $x=a^2=3b^2$ is not correct.

From $$ \frac{a}{b} = \frac{b}{a/3} \implies a^2/3 = b^2 \implies a^2=3b^2$$

So $a = \sqrt{3}b$ and thus $$x = \frac{a}{b} = \sqrt{3}$$

Comment: Please clarify how you got to $a^2/3 = b^2$

Comment: We have $${m\over n} = {p\over q}\iff mq=np$$

Comment: ok, let me work this out .....

Answer (score 1):

From this point
$$x=\frac{a}{b}=\frac{3b}{a}$$
you can multiply everything by $ab$, giving
$$abx = a^2 = 3b^2$$
Which is different from your next step.

Hint: if $x=\frac{a}{b}$, then what is $\frac{1}{x}$?